PHPDoc for Array that is Either Generic or Specific Structure
Using PhpStorm and trying to figure out the proper PHPDoc for a method that can either take a string string, or a generic array array<int|string, string>, or a very specific associative array array{sourceType: string, lotsOfOptionKeys?: string}. Gut instinct was to union them with | which works for string, numeric array of strings, and the very specific structure, but the generic array<string, string> appears to always trigger the specific shape check which then marks it as an error.
So the docblock ends up looking like this
/**
 * @param string | array<int|string, string> | array{
 *     sourceType: string, 
 *     lotsOfOptionKeys?: string
 * } $options
*/

✅ this works:
method('thisIsAString');

✅ so does this:
method(['a', 'b', 'c']);

✅ and so does this:
method(['sourceType' => 'asdfasd', 'lotsOfOptionKeys' => 'asfd']);

❌ but this errors and says it should be one of sourceType...:
method(['a' => 'AAA', 'b' => 'BBB']);


Why are you still using phpdoc instead of PHP's built-in type annotations?
